# How to use multiple colour scales in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, gradient, geom-raster

Given this matrix where on the x-axis are the latent values (1,2,3,4) and on the y-axis three levels for each drug (RAS, BB and AA). Each box of the matrix contains values between 0 and 1, I would like the boxes colored with an increasing colour gradient based on the value shown, with legends different for each drug.

Currently, for each row of each drug, the boxes are colored in the same color (RAS-ivory, BB-darkred, MRA-darkblue ). I would like to create three legends where each legend has a continuous scale of colors (from light to dark) and color the matrix according to its value.

```
#Dataframe
df <-data.frame(category=rep(c(0,1,2),12), 
                state=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3)), 
                value=runif(36), 
                drug = c(rep("RAS",12),rep("BB",12),rep("AA",12)),
               cat_drug = paste(rep(c(0,1,2),12),sep="_",c(rep("RAS",12),rep("BB",12), rep("AA",12))))

#Different color for each drug
color_scale <- c("RAS" = "ivory", "BB" = "darkred", "AA" = "darkblue")

ggplot(Psi, aes(y = cat_drug, x = state, fill = drug, label = round(value, 3))) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_text(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_scale, name = "Drug") +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = "Drug")) +
  labs(y = "Level of adherence", x = "Latent state") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0, vjust = 0.3),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.position = "right"
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

One option to have multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic  is to use the `ggnewscale` package. However, doing so requires some additional effort in that we have to use multiple `geom` layers, i.e. one for each of your `drug`s and of course multiple `scale`s. To avoid copy & paste I split the data by `drug`, then use `purrr::imap` to loop over the splitted data and add the layers. Unfortunately I ran in some issue with `geom_raster` so I switched to `geom_tile` which also requires to set the `height` of the tiles. Finally note that I use `scale_fill_distiller` and some of the Brewer color palettes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

df_split <- split(df, df$drug)
pal_drug <- c("RAS" = "Blues", "BB" = "Greens", "AA" = "Oranges")

set.seed(123)

ggplot(df, aes(y = cat_drug, x = state, label = round(value, 3))) +
  purrr::imap(df_split, function(x, y) {
    list(
      geom_tile(data = x, aes(fill = value), height = 1),
      scale_fill_distiller(
        palette = pal_drug[[y]], name = y,
        direction = 1, limits = c(0, 1)
      ),
      ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()
    )
  }) +
  geom_text(color = "black") +
  labs(y = "Level of adherence", x = "Latent state") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0, vjust = 0.3),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.position = "right"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `ggh4x` package offers one way to add multiple color (or fill) scales

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(scales)

ggplot(dat, aes(y = drug, x = state, label = round(value, 3))) +
  geom_raster(aes(rasf = value),
              data = ~subset(dat, drug == 'RAS')
              ) +
  geom_raster(aes(bbf = value),
              data = ~subset(dat, drug == 'BB')
              ) +
  geom_raster(aes(aaf = value),
              data = ~subset(dat, drug == 'AA')
              ) +
  scale_fill_multi(
    aesthetics = c('rasf','bbf','aaf'),
    name = list('ivory', 'darkred', 'darkblue'),
    colors = list(
      brewer_pal(palette = 'Greys')(4),
      brewer_pal(palette = 'PuRd')(4),
      brewer_pal(palette = 'Blues')(4)
    ),
    guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = unit(60, 'pt'),
                           title = "Drug")) +
  geom_text(color = "black")  +
  labs(y = "Level of adherence", x = "Latent state") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(category), ncol = 1, dir = 'v', strip.position = 'left') +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0, vjust = 0.3),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.position = "right",
    strip.placement = "outside"
  )
#> Warning in geom_raster(aes(rasf = value), data = ~subset(dat, drug == "RAS")):
#> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: rasf
#> Warning in geom_raster(aes(bbf = value), data = ~subset(dat, drug == "BB")):
#> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: bbf
#> Warning in geom_raster(aes(aaf = value), data = ~subset(dat, drug == "AA")):
#> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: aaf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice. Saw that `ggh4x` offers an option too. But haven't used it yet and forgot about it. Thx for the reminder. (: